# Как игнорировать автоинкремент поля id при duplicate?

Tags: mysql

Есть строка id = 1 и какое-то поле с индексом UNIQUE.
Пытаюсь вставить еще строку и вылазит ошибка о дублировании значения в индексе.
опять пробую вставить строку, но уже с другим значением уникального поля и строка вставляется, но id уже будет равен 3.
Как откатить или игнорировать autoincrement при duplicate? Зачем так вообще сделали?

Comment: Никак. Надо строить БД таким образом, что бы разрывы нумерации в ID не имели никакого значения. СУБД вообще имеет полное право выдавать ID даже не по возрастанию (хотя обычно так не делает). Для чего сделали - для быстрой работы вставок. Что бы была возможность откатить id необходимо делать полную блокировку таблицы на время вставки, а некоторые транзакции с вставками могут идти и полчаса и никто в это время не сможет производить другие вставки. Заметьте - практически все СУБД позволяющие автоматическое назначение ID ведут себя именно так

Comment: Понял, спасибо! Тогда вместо unique можно использовать простой index, а перед вставкой проверять, на существование такого значения. Только лишний запрос получается

Comment: А причем тут уникальность ? Уникальность и автоинкремент разные понятия. Поле может быть уникальным без автоинкремента и если логика работы подразумевает что одинаковых значений быть не может  надо делать unique. Вы лучше скажите, чем вам мешает пропуск ID=2, в 90% случаев если вам нужна последовательная нумерация - вы подошли к задаче не с той стороны. И кстати, будьте  осторожны с "сначала проверить, потом вставить", между этими двумя операциями другой процесс может  произвести свою вставку. Если это и делать, то одним запросом, благо SQL это позволяет.

Comment: Ну например регистрация. Поле email уникальное. Человек отправляет запрос, все ок, только вот email дублируется — возвращаем сообщение, и так какой-то дурак будет отправлять много раз, а очередность id нарушена. А хочется аккуратности.

Comment: Аккуратность - в том, что ID уникальны в течение всего времени существования таблицы. А вовсе не в том, что они типа "без дырок".

Comment: Все верно - делаете email уникальным и возвращаете ошибку при дубле. А то что ID потеряется, так это не страшно. Пользователей потом каких нибудь наверняка удалять захотите, так что дыры в нумерации по любому возникнут со временем. Так что нет смысла поддерживать последовательность, если в ней нет какого смысла для логики программы (а логику надо строить так, что бы ей было до фонаря какой там ID у записи)

Comment: Хорошо, понял. Всем спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

В `mysql` базах данных ключ id в таблице уникален и он не должен повторяться. Если вы хотите по значению одного поля находить несколько элементов, то имеет смысл ввести своё поле, например `my_id`.

Comment: Можно изменить id, и счетчик можно сменить, с какого будет продолжаться прибавление

Comment: Спасибо, поправил